# closed MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

We have MySql server 5.7 on a server. Additionally we have a different server that runs Ruby On Rails and connects to that server.

The problem is that after a few seconds when no one is using the program, when we try to connect, we get this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection
```

When the user tries again, the connection is done.

But why does it get disconnected at all?

In out MySql config we have:

```
max_connections        = 750
wait_timeout=28800
interactive_timeout=28800
```

Or maybe the answer is in Ruby?

Comment: when you say connecting MySQL on RoR is that any tool or client? because if you remember phpMyAdmin web client program it has a default connect timeout time of 1440 secs. It can be change by changing phpMyAdmin's setting file. I am guessing similar thing

Comment: Are you using the mysql2 gem? Do you have reconnect: true under production for your config/database.yml file?

Comment: yes, using MySQL gem. Also we have reconnect: true